# grab special attribute values on click

Tags: jquery

Check the code below. Html displays three images which contain a special attr called- `data-cc`. And all of those 3 images `data-cc` attr value stored on an array called- `coll`. What I want is when clicking on any of those images that `data-cc` value will be removed from the array named `coll`. Right now I'm already able to remove a specific value from array collection but the problem is I hardcoded on return `value != 1;` like this way. How can I remove value as per image clicked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coll = [];
  $('[data-cc]').each(function() {
    coll.push($(this).attr('data-cc'));
  });
  $("#fl").on("click", function() {
    coll = jQuery.grep(coll, function(value) {
      return value != 1;
    });
    console.log(coll);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fl">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="1" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="2" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="3" class="zastavica" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your `this` before making your `grep` function.

Also, you need to target `"#fl img"` in your click handler, not `"#fl"` :

```
$("#fl img").on("click", function () {
    var that = this;
    coll = jQuery.grep(coll, function(value) {
        return value != $(that).attr('data-cc');
    });
    console.log(coll);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coll = [];
  $('[data-cc]').each(function() {
    coll.push($(this).attr('data-cc'));
  });
  $("#fl img").on("click", function () {
    var that = this;
    coll = jQuery.grep(coll, function(value) {
        return value != $(that).attr('data-cc');
    });
    console.log(coll);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fl">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="1" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="2" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="3" class="zastavica" />
</p>
```

Comment: Or `var $that = $(this);` then you can do `$that.attr('data-cc');` without having to convert it to a jQuery object again. Alternatively keep the `that = this` and use `that.getAttribute('data-cc');` DRY!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` to get index of clicked `img` data attribute in array and if it exists in array use `splice` to remove it.

```js
const coll = $('[data-cc]').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-cc')
}).get()


$("#fl img").on("click", function () {
  const i = coll.indexOf($(this).attr('data-cc'))
  if(i != -1) coll.splice(i, 1)
  console.log(coll)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fl">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="1" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="2" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="3" class="zastavica" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep class names of all images as same then try below code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coll = [];
  $('[data-cc]').each(function() {
    coll.push($(this).attr('data-cc'));
  });
  $(".zastavica").on("click", function() {
    var v = $(this).attr('data-cc');
    coll = jQuery.grep(coll, function(value) {
      return value !== v;
    });
    console.log(coll);
  });
});
</script>

<p id="fl">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="1" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="2" class="zastavica" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHxsoJf.png" data-cc="3" class="zastavica" />
</p>
```